# Spring JPA Repository query method not case sensitive

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have been searching through the internet for this issue, what I have found are all about how to create a case insensitive query. I know a query is supposed to be case sensitive by default, but my repository will still return the result even though the capital and lowercase letters are different with the one in database.
**AccountRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Integer>
{
    Account findByPassword(String password);

    Account findByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password);
}
```

**AccountService.java**

```
public void login(Account entity)
{
    System.out.println(repository.findByUsernameAndPassword(
        entity.getUsername(), entity.getPassword());
    System.out.println(repository.findByPassword(
        entity.getPassword());
}
```

The service above, both will print out the correct result although the password is entered in wrong cases (like `mypassword` vs `MyPassword`). Any idea?

Comment: how is the db collation for those columns? i suspect a CI

Comment: What's your DB? It may be related to the code-page of your DB.

Comment: What do you mean? What I understand from your case is that it's the same entering "mypassword" and "myPassword". If that's your case, I'd recomment you customising the query with `@Query` annotation.

Comment: It must be the collation type for the password column. See whether it has '_ci' at the end which stands for case insensitive.

Comment: Check if collations is '_bin'

Comment: yes, the table collation is `utf_general_ci`, so should I change it to `utf_bin`? since it is the only collection that doesn't follow with `ci` at the end.

Comment: and my database table was created by JPA Entity class, is there any method to set the collection type in entity class?

Comment: actually you want utf_general_cs. cs/ci stands for case sensitive/insensitive

Comment: I don't see any `_cs` collection in options.

Comment: Did you try with findByPasswordIgnoreCase?

Comment: @notionquest No, how can I use IgnoreCase when I want it to be case sensitive instead of insensitive?

Answer (score 0):

In the example of

```
findByPassword
```

It splits it on key word then case so :

```
find  by  password
```

where password is a property

In the example of

```
findByUsernameAndPassword
```

This becomes

```
find  by  username  and  password
```

where username and password are properties.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods

Your database may have a case insensitive switch set. MySql allows this, Oracle does not.